# Why is my UnwindSegue animated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a VC A. In this VC in my Implementation is:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {

UIViewController *sourceViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController;

}
```

I call my unwindSegue in VC B:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToMenu" sender:self];
```

The Segue has the right Identifier in my Storyboard and the Checkbox "Animates" is unchecked. But my UnwindSegue is still animating. The vc b comes from left to right... Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
```

In the unwind function of the VC that you are unwinding to. This should turn off any animations.

Comment: just this way? isn't working - (IBAction)unwindToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {

UIViewController *sourceViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController; [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];

}

Comment: Then i think that something has changed in the last few iOS updates, as i can see similar behavior in my own apps. I am going to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom Segue and override "performs" , in here you do your removal of the VC without animation.

Comment: i have now a custom segue, but whats the best way to present the parent VC embedded in navcontroller without animation? just popviewcontroller?

Comment: I have tried doing that, and sometimes I can still see the animation, but at a much bigger speed. This was not an issue before iOS9.